# Is there any library/software available that can give me useful measurements of image quality?

Tags: image-processing

I realise measuring image quality in software is going to be really difficult, and I'm not looking for a quick-fix. Googling this is largely showing up research papers and discussions that go a bit over my head, so I was wondering if anyone in the SO community had any experience with doing any rough image quality assessment?

I want to use this to scan a few thousand images and whittle it down to a few dozen images that are most likely of poor quality. I could then show these to a user and leave the rest to them.

Obviously there are many metrics that can be a part of whether an image is of high/low quality, I'd be happy with anything that could take an image as an input and give some reasonable metrics to any of the basic image quality metrics like sharpness, dynamic range, noise, etc., leaving it up to my software to determine what's acceptable and what isn't.

Some of the images are poor quality because they've been up-scaled drastically. If there isn't a way of getting metrics like I suggested above, is there any way to detect that an image has been up-scaled like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very difficult question since "image quality" is not a very well defined concept.

It's probably best if you start experimenting with some basic metrics and see if you come up with a measure that suits your applications.

E.g., for dynamic range, the quantiles of the distributions of each channel can yield interesting information.

For up-scaling, on the other hand, the solution is fairly simple: just do a fourier transform on the image and see the amount of energy in the high-frequency vs lower-frequency bands.

Comment: Yeah I realise it's tricky, and I'm happy to experiment with basic metrics, I just don't really know how to get at any of them. I don't have any experience with image processing at all so a starting point would be great.

Comment: Quantiles: usually computed via histograms or sorting. I.e. sort the image and take the values of r, g, b (and probably gray as well) at 10, 25, 50, 75, 90% of the image. 90%-10% will give you an idea of how much dynamic range there is.

Comment: And for scaling, the answer is as I said, compute the fourier transform and then compute the energy up to certain radius, and compute the ratios of these.

Comment: I have no idea what most of that means, but you've at least given me some starting points to work it out. Thanks.